# Issues while fixing a div using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to fix my header to the to so for that i have used

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="row">
 </div>
</div>
```

the row gets fixed but it is transparent and the rest of the content which is beneath the row is now starting for the top of the browser thus overlapping occurs between some parts how can it be solved. Please help. Thanks...

Comment: hmm...looks okay to me and its also working for me. I' am guessing that something in your CSS which is overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the BootStrap demo for fixed header, http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Check the page source and look at the CSS (navbar-fixed-top.css) file for the page, shown below:

```
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

In short, they're setting a padding on the body element to counter the navbar's height, forcing the remaining content to be drawn 'below' it.

You may need to do something similar.